# How to add a background image to a button in pygame gui?

Tags: user-interface, button, background, pygame

I am trying to add an image as a background of a button in pygame gui. I have the button created now and I just need to add the image. How can I add the image to the button?

This is my code

```
   game1 = pygame.Rect(150 , 100, 200, 150) # creates a rect object
   pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 100, 0], game1) # draw objects down here
```

it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `pygame.Surface.blit` (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)

Load your background image and blit it wherever you want.

```
img = pygame.image.load('thisisanimage.png')
WhateverYourDisplayNameIs.blit(img,(x,y))
```

Just in case you're confused, it looks like you're using `screen` as your display surface.

Comment: Can you please do me a favour and show me a code example?@Larry

Comment: Don't forget to name your button image `button_img` https://pastebin.com/DFmKLp0s

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot